# Front wheel scraping noise

Tags: brakes, noise, saab

I have some weird scraping/rubbing noise in my right front wheel. I
I hear it regardless of weather i brake or not, and the slower i go the more low pitched and grindy it sounds. It continues to scrape at normal driving speeds, but is very high pitched and not very noticeable. I do not hear it as much while in reverse.

what I have checked/tried.

1. brakes look ok, the caliper must be sliding properly since there is even wear on both inside and outer pads.
2. rotor looked pretty good but possibly warped.
3. I replaced the front brakes and rotors, but am still hearing the noise
4. It occours less when I am in reverse, or when Im turning right. It is more apparent while turning left, but it is happening all of the time.

so at this point I think it might be a wheel hub bearing, but it's not  'wubwubwub' noise everyone describes it as.

Here's the noise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN30O-m8CpY

Comment: Does the car have disk brakes all the way around? It sounds like one of two things: either a drum on the rear of a vehicle (experienced the same sound on my truck), or it could be a dust cover on the disks brakes on the front.

Comment: It does not appear to be the dust cover, i will double check that, and it is disc brakes all around.

Comment: What year & model is your Saab? Or if it isn't a Saab, what make is it as well :P

Comment: 2001 Saab 9-3 Viggen

Comment: Could it be the wheel bearing?

Comment: It could be, but from my experience, you'll feel a wheel bearing issue more than you'll hear it. It would have to get *pretty bad* before you'd hear it, then the wheel will almost be falling off ... well, maybe that's what's happening, lol (let's hope not).

Comment: could it be a caliper sticking partially or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22220/discussion-between-mutantturkey-and-paulster2).

Comment: a CLlhghghhgllgh is a broken brake pad, dangling against the rotor

Comment: ­@Paulster2 On some car you heard it way more than it alter the feel. I had a 98 Vw Passat in witch car it was the case (Really noisy but no different feeling in the driving)

Comment: You might try using these procedures to locate the precise problem. http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/21931/12743

Comment: @MutantTurkey  have been able to resolve this?  If so, can you answer your own question and award yourself the answer?  If not, where are you stuck at in the troubleshooting process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely does sound like a bad wheel hub bearing. Classic pattern of woob-woob-woob-woob. The sound is made as the bearing inner race wobbles around the outer race. This is a safety issue. Replace as soon as possible.

Did you take a look at the CV joints? A bad CV boot could have damaged the bearing by filling it up with gunk (a mix of dirt and grease). Like liquid sandpaper...

Comment: Confirmed wheel bearing. Front right replaced. Hub and bearing both were shot.

Comment: @MutantTurkey   Could you award Race Fever with the answer since he nailed it?

Comment: @DucatiKiller Its all right. I'm just here to help. =)